# Using regex in Ruby/Capybara case statement throws 'Regex matched 0 arguments' error

Tags: regex, ruby, capybara

I'm testing a site using Cucumber/Selenium Web-driver & Capybara
I'm trying to build a case statment in my step_definition so that I don't have multiple "given" for each page on my site.

I've got the following:

```ruby
Given /^I am on the .+ page$/ do |page_name|
  case page_name
  when "I am on the home page"
   visit ('/')
  else
    puts "page #{page_name} not found"
  end 
end
```

When i run `cucumber` in the terminal to run the tests i get

> Given I am on the home page # features/step_definitions/home_page.rb:3
>   Your block takes 1 argument, but the Regexp matched 0 arguments. (Cucumber::Glue::ArityMismatchError)
>   features/step_definitions/home_page.rb:3:in `/^I am on the .+ page$/'
>   features/homepage.feature:5:in`Given I am on the home page'

I've tried wrapping the regex in (), {}, [], " ", '' and various combinations of these, I've checked the indentation of my code and i *think* it's correct.

I've put my Regex in to an online validator and it picks it up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block is taking a parameter `page_name` but your Regex doesn't have a capture group in it to be used as that parameter.  You probably want something like

```
Given /^I am on the (.+) page$/ do |page_name|
```

so the `.+` portion is captured and passed through as `page_name`